# Twig: Replace every instance of a string

Tags: replace, twig

Is there a way in Twig to replace a defined string A with another string B throughout the whole system? Meaning that whenever I output anything (variable, static content, translation, ...) there is a process that checks the content for A and replaces it with B.

Is there some kind of listener or event I can hook in to do this?

I know there are `replace` filters within Twig, but I don't want to define them in every instance, but be sure that it's going to be replaced everywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first solution would be to define a custom "node visitor" for Twig. The [Twig_NodeVisitor_Optimizer](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/1.x/lib/Twig/NodeVisitor/Optimizer.php) is an example of how to change the contents of a template without having to add any special function, filter or tag.

However, defining a "node visitor" is extremely complex and I'd recommend you instead to solve this issue in an alternative way:

- If you use Twig inside Symfony, use the [kernel.response event](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/events.html#kernel-response) to get the response and apply a simple `str_replace()` or `preg_replace()` function to its contents before delivering them to the user.
- If you use Twig independently, apply the same technique to the output generated by the `render()` method.